# Custom map route is not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an custom mvc route it's not working. if i define the route before home route then it's working otherwise not.

this code is not working.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

       routes.MapRoute(
          "Citysearch",
         "{state}",
         new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "GetDynamicContent" }
       );
```

when i define the `citysearch` first then it's working something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "Citysearch",
             "{state}",
             new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "GetDynamicContent" }
           );

       routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and another problem is this is the url of city search  `http://localhost:51381/dynamic-content`. `dynamic-content` this is my state paramter. It's calling of my `Dashboard/GetDynamicContent`. but problem is when application run after login url is `http://localhost:51381/Home` it is calling always `Dashboard/GetDynamicContent` how to get rid of this problem please help me.

Comment: can you explain why custom route is required, you can have Action as GetDynamicContent(string state) in your Dashboard Controller

Comment: there is a grid. gird have anchor when i click this anchor this custom route. means i want to open the new page on that anchor. anchor name is parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Routes are read from top to bottom. Therefore, the first route match will be used when routing.

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "Home/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Citysearch",
    "DynamicContent/{state}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "GetDynamicContent" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: so what will we do for custom route..?

Comment: Always put custom routes on top

Comment: but another problem is it is consider my controller name as a paramter... what can i do for fix this issue..?

Comment: Add a url parameter to your CitySearch route. Something like `url: "foobar/{state}",`

Comment: can i do this "foobar/" without giving this?

Comment: Yes. You may need to define another route for /Home to override this behavior. @Karan is right.

Comment: can you please give me some code? how can i do this. And another thing there is not necessary controller name is home. I have lots of controller name..

Comment: I updated my answer. Edited: you might need to do this for every controller you have. Adding the `"foobar/"` will save you the headache.

Comment: If you're using `DynamicContent/` in `Citysearch` then first routes.MapRoute for `Home` will not be required. It will work fine without that mapping also.

Comment: for example if i have another controller like http://localhost:51381/EmployeeSalary who's and i am not using this 'DynamicContent/' so we have to define 'EmployeeSalary' in route config right..?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some fix part in your url as shown below `DynamicContent/` to solve issue you are facing. And your url should be like `http://localhost:51381/DynamicContent/dynamic-content`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Citysearch",
    "DynamicContent/{state}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "GetDynamicContent" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: can i do this without giving any injector..?

Comment: No. Because if you are not injecting anything then if you try to access url `http://localhost:51381/Home`, the `Home` will be considered as value for `{state}` and it will redirect to `Citysearch` route.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my experience in this issue "custom-map-route is not working".

Myobservation:custom url routing not working when page is redirected using href="redirected page" . when i am using @Url.Action() for redirection then custom routing started working.

here is my initial code(peice of code)

return '<a  href="/Home/AuthorityForm?formid=' + '@ViewBag.formid' + "&SubmittedFormId=" + full.ConsentId + """ + 'target="_blank">ViewForm';

i changed to

var link = '@Url.Action("AuthorityForm", "Home", new { formid = ViewBag.formid, SubmittedFormId = "-1" })';
link = link.replace("-1", full.ConsentId);
return 'ViewForm'

this may help someone..